# How to proxypass Apache to a dockerized Flask/Gunicorn app

Tags: docker, apache, flask, proxy

We have a server running apache2 that is hosting a number of websites and applications. We have a dockerized Flask application (served with Gunicorn) that we would like to deploy on the server and have Apache direct traffic to it. Basically `https://oneofoursites.com/flask_app` redirects to the port Docker is exposing for the Flask app. Right now, the site works fine if you navigate to `https://oneofoursites.com:4000/`.

I first attempted something like this in a apache.conf under sites-available:

```
ProxyPass /flask_app http://127.0.0.1:4000/ connectiontimeout=3600 timeout=3600
ProxyPassReverse /flask_app http://127.0.0.1:4000/
<Location /flask_app >
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

The flask app is now available at `https://oneofoursites.com/flask_app`, but none of the links work.

The [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#deploying-proxy-setups) was slightly helpful, but not close enough to my case. I cannot seem to get Flask to pick up the environment variables (since it is inside a Docker container), so couldn't get it to reform the headers itself. I looked into [mod_wsgi](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/), but am unsure how to deploy it (inside the Docker container and Apache won't run it; outside the container how do I get it to redirect to the Flask app?). Most guides I am finding are recommending Nginx, so perhaps I need to deploy Nginx (either in the existing Flask container or a separate one with docker-compose)? Would it then act as a suitable go between for Apache and the Flask app?

Comment: I would run nginx/ apache on another container and use docker-compose. Just remember to you need to bind ports to external ports to allow apache to pick it up from outside of docker

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the env-variable SCRIPT_NAME to your url-path when starting gunicorn.
In your case something like

```
gunicorn -e SCRIPT_NAME=/flask_app --bind 127.0.0.1:4000 app:app
```